# Add or draw custom routes in Google Maps without constraints

Tags: google-maps, route, google-mymaps

I'm trying to create a custom route in Google Maps but when I get to a certain point where Google does not have a road defined, I cannot draw the route outside of the road even though when I go to Google Maps and switch to Satellite layer, I can see the road.

I am able to draw shapes without this restriction, however. Is there any way to draw routes in free form?